# How to remove suspicious Chrome extension in Mac OS

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Recently I find my Chrome browser always warns that some plug-in is blocked when opening a new tap. After I go to the "Manage Plug-in exceptions" pages:
[image]

The first one is a suspicious extension but I don't know how to remove it. 
Thanks for any suggestion.

regards,
pigling

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?hl=en:

> Simply hover over the site or domain and click the X that appears and then click Done.

Comment: Thanks but the suspicious "Hostname Pattern" doesn't have the X button as others.